# Smooth Transition in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Is tkinter able to make a smooth text transition(slowly appear into the Window)? In Windows 10, *Python 3* ? I have tried searching through the web but no similar questions, I have tried seeing if the widget has an option to do that, but no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is tkinter able to make a smooth text transition

If you are talking about a tkinter.Label, then you may be able to fake it by interpolating between two colors (the start color being the background color of the label, the end color being the desired foreground color of the label). Here's an example I came up with, where a label fades in from the background color (to fake transparency) into the desired foreground color (red in this case):

```
import tkinter as tk

def interpolate(color_a, color_b, t):
    # 'color_a' and 'color_b' are RGB tuples
    # 't' is a value between 0.0 and 1.0
    # this is a naive interpolation
    return tuple(int(a + (b - a) * t) for a, b in zip(color_a, color_b))


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Font Color Test")
        self.geometry("256x64")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello World", pady=32)
        self.label.pack()

        # On my system (Windows 7, classic theme) this is "SystemButtonFace"
        label_background_system_color = self.label.cget("background")

        label_background_16_bit_color = self.label.winfo_rgb(label_background_system_color)

        # Again, on my system, this is RGB(212, 208, 200)
        label_background_8_bit_color = tuple(value >> 8 for value in label_background_16_bit_color)

        # This isn't really required. Making a custom label foreground color just to show it doesn't have to be black.
        label_foreground_8_bit_color = tuple((255, 0, 0))

        # I want the the label to "fade in" from the background color to completely red
        self.start_color = label_background_8_bit_color
        self.end_color = label_foreground_8_bit_color

        # Let's say I want a smooth fade in transition at a rate of 60 fps and a duration of 1 second

        self.duration_ms = 1000
        self.frames_per_second = 60
        self.ms_sleep_duration = 1000 // self.frames_per_second
        self.current_step = 0

        self.update_label()


    def update_label(self):

        t = (1.0 / self.frames_per_second) * self.current_step
        self.current_step += 1

        new_color = interpolate(self.start_color, self.end_color, t)
        self.label.configure(foreground="#%02x%02x%02x" % new_color)

        if self.current_step <= self.frames_per_second:
            self.after(self.ms_sleep_duration, self.update_label)


def main():

    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: How About With New Tabs ```Toplevel```?

Comment: TopLevel as in a pop-up window? As in, make the whole popup window fade in or out? In that case I don't know - probably not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to fake it using images. Use a timeout function to replace them one after the other. Not sure if that would be fast enough to appear smooth.

But for things like this I think other toolkits would be better suited. For example pysdl2.

Comment: I only started considering going to another GUI dev framework.